# How to setup multiple Environments in CypressJs

Tags: vue.js, vuex, cypress

I haven't been able to figure out how to setup my cypressJs environments correctly to test. I'd love some help.

In my `index.html` file, in the `<script>` area, i am adding a `CONFIG` object. In production, this config object is added in by the MVC app.  This config object can have many different states (some info might be missing or different for each user). In the `cypress.json` file, under "env" I have this same object. I use this in the `spec.js` files by calling `Cypress.env("CONFIG");` which works just fine.

However, I want to change the state of the app/environment variable for different tests. Is this possible?

I'd like to run a spec file using a `CONFIG` that has all the data and one spec file using a `CONFIG` object that is missing data (ex. address == null) so I can test properly under both circumstances.

Is this possible or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <script>
    CONFIG = {
    dealer: {
          id: 19285,
          address: "343 Somewhere Lane SpringField, TN 47383",
          name: "HUDSON TRACTOR & RENTAL EQUIPMENT & OTHER HEAVY THINGS
   }
   </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

`cypress.json`

```
{
 "env": {
   "CONFIG": {
      dealer: {
          id: 19285,
          address: "343 Somewhere Lane SpringField, TN 47383",
          name: "HUDSON TRACTOR & RENTAL EQUIPMENT & OTHER HEAVY THINGS
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more of a best practice to run spec files against a single environment one at a time. It is either you use an overriding `cypress.env.json` or create 2 config files for each environment (test and prod for example) which will override env variables both set in `cypress.env.json` and `cypress.json`. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-2-cypress-env-json

However, if you want a quick and dirty solution to your issue above (I don't suggest this), you can set your spec files with the below:

**cypress.json**

```
{
 "env": {
   "CONFIG": {
    "id": "19285",
    "address": "343..."
    },
   "CONFIG_PROD": {
    "id": "19285",
    "address": ""
    }
 }
}
```

**spec_1.js**

```
const config = Cypess.env("CONFIG")
```

**spec_2.js**

```
const config = Cypress.env("CONFIG_PROD")
```

or just simply put them under fixture files (which I believe is more appropriate for this case):
**config.json**

```
   {
    "test": {
        "id": "19285",
        "address": "343..."
    },
    "prod": {
        "id": "19285",
        "address": ""
    }
   }
```

**spec_1.js**

```
import {test, prod} from '../fixtures/config.json'
const address = test.address
const address_null = prod.address //If you would like to run this on another 'it' test
```

**spec_1.js**

```
import {prod} from '../fixtures/config.json'
const address_null = prod.address
```

Comment: This sounds great but I am using that "CONFIG" property in the index.html file also to essentially "seed" the app while testing/developing. How would i replace this with various versions and also keep in sync which one i'm using during testing?